# How to tell what Version of MongoDB you are Running

Tags: php, mongodb, version, drivers

When I look at the output from `phpinfo()` it states `mongodb version 1.1.2`.

When I run `db.version()` in Robomongo it states `3.2.1`.

Why does `phpinfo()` give me a different version to that from Robomongo?

Also, how can I tell if I have the latest PHP Drivers for MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from `phpinfo()` is the PHP driver version.
The `db.version()` in Robomongo shows the MongoDB core version.

This [page](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/) provides information on the current drivers available.

As of this posting, you have the latest version of the driver and MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you @metame. My rep does not yet allow me to upvote so please know I upvoted this in spirit.

Answer (score 0):

`phpinfo()` returns the version of your PHP Mongo driver, whereas as Robomongo is returning the version of your Mongo instance. According to [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/RELEASE-1.1), the latest release for the PHP driver is `1.1.2`, so you are using the most recent PHP driver for MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you @Jaco. My rep does not yet allow me to upvote so please know I upvoted this in spirit.

Comment: I accepted @metame's answer for this q because his answer addresses the core of my initial question. I added another question to my OQ because when I went to post part 2 separately in SO it wanted me to wait 90 minutes to post again. But thank you for your answer as it is helpful (at)Jaco.